# How Do I Display A Single Program Via A Projector?

Tags: clock, pi, projector

Forgive me, ladies and mentalmen, I'm not what I once was. I have cancer and the chemo has wrecked my brain and memory.

The problem. I want to build a cheap system to do one thing. Display a program. Specifically, the World Clock by Fulvio Castelli. https://www.worldclock.ws/

I've bought a license for both the program and the screensaver. I was thinking of using a Raspberry Pi with an HDMI output to a cheap projector. The projector would then display the clock on the wall 24/7.

What *exactly* would I need to build this and make it happen. I've been fascinated by this clock for almost 30 years now, since I saw a giant version in a multi-national board room. I was gobsmacked and thought "How cool is that!"

Now, in the twilight of my life I'd like to have one of these in my man-cave. A few short years ago I could have cobbled together something in an afternoon. But cancer has ravaged my mind and I have very little short-term memory and almost no powers of concentration. But given a list of components (Amazon links would be a great help) and basic instructions I'm sure I could build this.

So could someone help me out?

Thank you.

Legless

[image: World Clock]

Comment: Hi Legless. First off, I'm very sorry for your situation and the difficulties you're facing, but I'm not sure you'll get much good help here on Stackoverflow since most people here's expertise is focused specifically in programming rather than project such as this. I'm not aware of another good StackExchange community to point you towards, but a subredidit like https://www.reddit.com/r/DIY_tech/ seems like a good start.

Comment: Thanks Christian. I'll try over there....

Comment: Speaking towards your question, though, with the limited knowledge I have on building such a project, I think your concept of using a raspberry pi makes sense. You should be able to load windows on a raspberry pi computer like this one https://www.raspberrypi.com/products/raspberry-pi-4-model-b/, and hook up a monitor and projector to display the world clock program. Best of luck to you.

Comment: And no problem.